# Embed view and set filter from CCK field

Tags: 6, views

I created a view with 3 filters. I embedded the view in my tpl.php file for the content type. My question is, how can I set some filter with the value from a CCK field?

This is the code I use:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->set_display('default');
$view->filters[2]['value'] = $node->field_name[0]['value'];
if (!empty($view)) {
    print $view->execute_display($display_id , $view_args);
}
```

Comment: Can I get a certain set of rows using an argument instead of a filter? Is there any way to pass the argument programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arguments instead of filters on your view. That way you can use [views_embed_view](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--views.module/function/views_embed_view/6).

Just add an argument to the view with the same field you would use as a filter. That adds a where condition to the views query in a similar way as a filter would do.

Then pass on the CCK field value as the third argument on your template file like this:

```
print views_embed_view('view_name', 'default', $node->field_name[0]['value']);
```

Comment: what if I want to pass two values for the same argument, e.g. tid[]=1&tid[]=2?

Answer (score 0):

you could always use like this:

`views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default', 'your first arg', 'second arg', 'so on', 'so forth');`